# How do I get the number of lines in a string?

Tags: string, go

How do I find out how many lines are in a string in Go?

Is there a builtin function, or do I have to "manually" search the string for all newlines +1?

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func NumLines(s string) int {
    n := strings.Count(s, "\n")
    if !strings.HasSuffix(s, "\n") {
        n++
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    s := "line 1\nline 2\nline 3"
    fmt.Println(NumLines(s))
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: That's a shame, I was hoping for a built-in `strings.NumLines()`. (It makes the code clearer)

Comment: Regarding `HasSuffix`, you don't consider `line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n` to be four lines long? Is that a personal preference, or some kind of standard?

Comment: @IQAndreas: In Go, write your own NumLines function. See my revised answer.

Comment: @IQAndreas: For `line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n`, how do you count to four lines? I only see three lines.

Comment: Even though only three lines have text on them, there is a fourth empty line after `line3`. It's like the existentialist question _"Is an emtpy string still a string?"_

Comment: @IQAndreas: The existential question is "how many substrings does an empty string have?" Is it zero, one, or an infinite number. It's zero. Therefore, an empty string has zero lines. [Substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)

Comment: What about `line\n\n\nline`? With that same logic, the String only has 2 lines, when I would argue, it is 4 lines long.